# I vote on a card, it shows as 2 votes for some reason, why?

Tags: trello

When I vote on any card I am getting "2 votes (with you)". Somehow I once was able to remove one of the votes to show only the one I intended to display. I am not understanding why if I click to place a vote, it shows two votes. Is this a bug or intentional and if it is intentional then why would it show as 2 votes?

Comment: I also ran into this issue.  If possible, could you report this to support@trello.com ?

Comment: This does sound like it's a bug that should be reported directly to Trello.

Comment: You're just that important, your vote counts twice as much :)

Answer (score 0):

I emailed support, and it is a bug to be fixed.

Hi Chris,

That's a known issue that will be fixed in a future release!

All the best,

Ben